# How to format JSON data with brackets []

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net

I have write the follow code to get the data formated as JSON

```
{"billNumber":"0003","entityActivityId":572,"customerFullName":"التوكيلات التجارية","customerMobileNumber":"0506436506","customerPreviousBalance":0,"issueDate":"2022-08-16","expireDate":"2022-09-23","billItemList":{"name":"*","quantity":1,"unitPrice":900,"discount":0,"discountType":"FIXED","vat":"0.15"}}
```

but I want to be as follwoing:

the deferrence is the [] in the details data.

```
{"billNumber":"0003","entityActivityId":572,"customerFullName":"التوكيلات التجارية","customerMobileNumber":"0506436506","customerPreviousBalance":0,"issueDate":"2022-08-16","expireDate":"2022-09-23","billItemList":[{"name":"*","quantity":1,"unitPrice":900,"discount":0,"discountType":"FIXED","vat":"0.15"}]}
```

my code is :

```
dt1 = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
        dt2 = dt.AddDays(7).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
        Dim b As New billItemList With
        {
        .name = "*",
        .quantity = 1,
        .unitPrice = txtSubTotal.Value,
        .discount = txtDiscountValue.Value,
        .discountType = "FIXED",
        .vat = 0.15
        }

        
        Dim person = New EfaaAPI() With {
        .billNumber = txtInvNo.Value,
        .entityActivityId = 572,
        .customerFullName = CN,
        .customerMobileNumber = txtTelNo.Value,
        .issueDate = dt1,
        .expireDate = dt2,
                     .billItemList = b
         }

        Dim json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person)
```

my class is :

```
Public Class EfaaAPI


Public Property billNumber As String 'optional
Public Property entityActivityId As Integer
Public Property customerFullName As String
Public Property customerMobileNumber As String
Public Property customerPreviousBalance As Integer
Public Property issueDate As String  'YYYY-MM-DD
Public Property expireDate As String 'YYYY-MM-DD
Public Property billItemList As New billItemList()
```

End Class

```
Public Class billItemList
Public Property name As String
Public Property quantity As Integer
Public Property unitPrice As Integer
Public Property discount As Integer
Public Property discountType As String
Public Property vat As String
```

End Class

any idea regarding this issue ??

Comment: This is because **billItemList** is an object in your code and not **IEnumerable**, **List** or an **Array**. Convert this into an array or list then you will have array in your json as well.

Comment: Make `billItemList` (the property) a, well, `List` as the name suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to fix the class

```
     Public Class EfaaAPI
        // .... another properties
        Public Property billItemList As List(Of billItem)
     End Class
```

change the name of class

```
Public Class billItem
Public Property name As String
//.....
End Class
```

and code

```
  Dim b As New List(Of billItem) From
        {
    New billItem With {
      .name = "d",
      .quantity = 572,
     //...
    }
}
 Dim person = New EfaaAPI With {
        //....
        .expireDate = dt2,
        .billItemList = b
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing :

```
Public Class EfaaAPI
Public Property billNumber As String 'optional
Public Property entityActivityId As Integer
Public Property customerFullName As String
Public Property customerMobileNumber As String
Public Property customerPreviousBalance As Integer
Public Property issueDate As String  'YYYY-MM-DD
Public Property expireDate As String 'YYYY-MM-DD
Public Property billItemList As New billItemList()
End Class
```

to

```
Public Class EfaaAPI
Public Property billNumber As String 'optional
Public Property entityActivityId As Integer
Public Property customerFullName As String
Public Property customerMobileNumber As String
Public Property customerPreviousBalance As Integer
Public Property issueDate As String  'YYYY-MM-DD
Public Property expireDate As String 'YYYY-MM-DD
Public Property billItemList As New List(Of billItemList)()
End Class
```

and try changing :

```
Dim person = New EfaaAPI() With {
         .billNumber = txtInvNo.Value,
         .entityActivityId = 572,
         .customerFullName = CN,
         .customerMobileNumber = txtTelNo.Value,
         .issueDate = dt1,
         .expireDate = dt2,
         .billItemList = b 
     }
```

to :

```
Dim person = New EfaaAPI() With {
        .billNumber = "d",
        .entityActivityId = 572,
        .customerFullName = "ss",
        .customerMobileNumber = "ss",
        .issueDate = "ss",
        .expireDate = "ds",
        .billItemList = New List(Of billItemList)({b})

       }
```

Comment: now I am receiving error in:

.billItemList = b

 Value of type 'billItemList' cannot be converted to 'List(Of billItemList)'.

Comment: I put the correct code below, take a look  here `.billItemList = New List(Of billItemList)({b})`

Comment: @MohamedZaher it would also be prudent to note that your class `billItemList` should also be named properly. Classes should be named using PascalCasing.